How to display macOS volume HUD when changing volume from Bluetooth headset?
I have a Beats headset, and it is very convenient to set the volume from it directly via Bluetooth, which works fine. My only problem is, that when I do that, the system volume HUD is not displayed. Is it possible to display it somehow similar to the keyboard volume keys?
